# MailApp.sendEmail failed

Tags: javascript, sendmail

I have a script to automatically send an email.

Unfortunately the script suddenly stopped working. I have changed nothing within the code.

Can you help me?

script:

```
function SendEmail() {
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DEST").getRange("A2:A30");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
var subject = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName()
var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "Esteemed,\n\nAttached is the "+subject, {attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]})
 }`
```

Error:

> Exception: The parameters (number[],String,String,(class)) don't match
>   the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail. (line 6, file "Code")

Comment: The error says that you are passing an array of type `number` as the first parameter. The name `emailAddress` suggests that this is not what you intended to do.

Comment: If nothings changed here then somethings changed somewhere else. If youve checked the obvious like "is the compuer connected to the internet", etc then Id have a look at MailApp. Has it changed? Does it rely on scripts held on external sites which may have changed? Go to the hosts of the external script providers and see if any changes have been announced.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling Chrome V8 by going to the menu:

**Run > Disable new Apps Script Runtime powered by Chrome V8.**

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the email address is a type number.  Coerce it to a string by using `.toString()`

```
MailApp.sendEmail(
  address.toString()
  subject,
  "Esteemed,\n\nAttached is the "+subject,
  {
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
  }
)
```