# MailApp.sendEmail failed (Error: Exception: Invalid Email)

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script to automatically send emails after we receive a form, it was working fine until about a week ago (I haven't changed the code).

I tried disabling Chrome V8, and also .toString() to try and change it from type number, but it didn't work. (as oriented here: [MailApp.sendEmail failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484164/mailapp-sendemail-failed)).

Can anybody help?

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = data[i][0] + "," + data[i][1];
    var subject = data[i][3]; 
    var cc = data[i][5];
    var message = "Test message.";    
    var emailSent = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 11).getValue();     
    if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT") {  
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {name: "Team", replyTo: "contact@company.com", cc: cc});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 11).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Error:
Exception: Invalid Email:
sendMail @Code.gs:14

Comment: Put `console.log(data[i][0] + "," + data[i][1])` before the line `var emailAddress = data[i][0] + "," + data[i][1];` and check what it logs on the iteration that it fails.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the error is clear:
`Error: Exception: Invalid Email: sendMail @Code.gs:14`

```
var emailAddress = data[i][0] + "," + data[i][1];
...
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {name: "Team", replyTo: "contact@company.com", cc: cc});
```

I'm not sure what's in `data` but commas are generally not part of a valid email address. A valid local-part of an email address contains:

- uppercase and lowercase Latin letters `A` to `Z` and `a` to `z`
- digits `0` to `9`
- printable characters `` !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~ ``
- dot `.`, provided that it is not the first or last character and provided also that it does not appear consecutively (e.g., John..Doe@example.com is not allowed).

Space and special characters `"(),:;<>@[\]` are only allowed are only allowed inside a quoted string

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax for full details. Also review: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?hl=en

I stumbled across this question suffering a similar error, however in my case I needed to ensure my `e.parameters.email` resolved to a string first.

That solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71167219/19157546

Comment: I don't think that was the user's error. The user was trying to separate two email addresses with a comma. That's acceptable.