# Apps Script MailApp throwing error : Exception: Invalid email: [L<?> (line 11, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send an email from app script by triggering a deployment. My code is as below:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return SendMail(e);
}
function doPost(e) {
  return SendMail(e);
}
function SendMail(e) {
  var recipient = e.parameters.recipient;
  var body = e.parameters.body;
        MailApp.sendEmail({
            to: recipient,
            subject: "Test Mail",
            htmlBody: "Dear Sir/ Madam, <br> Test Code " +body+ ,
            name: "Test App"
                    });
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(recipient)
}
```

However its throwing an error:

> Exception: Invalid email: [L<?> (line 11, file "Code")

I am properly passing the email Id. If I return the conterService,createTextOutput with recipient variable, it returns the proper email id.

Comment: Your recipient is an invalid email address.  If you are passing the email id that won't work it must be the email address

Comment: have you tried printing the `recipient` value? this could easily be verified by doing that. Most likely the answer @Tanaike provided below would fix your issue. If it worked, have the decency to confirm if it by accepting/upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

About `var recipient = e.parameters.recipient;`, in this case, `recipient` is an array. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var recipient = e.parameters.recipient;
```

#### To:

```
var recipient = e.parameter.recipient;
```

or

```
var recipient = e.parameters.recipient[0];
```

#### Note:

- In your script, it seems that Web Apps is used. **In this case, when you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#eventobject)